# authentication with angular js / json

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, authentication

i tried to make login form with angular js

i have list of user in json file but i can't  comapre with the  input text from login form

User.json :

```
[{
    "username": "user1",
    "password": "pass1"
}, {
    "username": "user2",
    "password": "pass2"
}, {
    "username": "user3",
    "password": "pass3"
}, {
    "username": "user4",
    "password": "pass4"
}]
```

script.js

```
var app1 = angular.module('app1', []);
var app2 = angular.module('app2', []);
var app = angular.module('app', ['app1', 'app2']);

app1.controller('jsonCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('data.json')
        .then(function(res) {
            $scope.users = res.data;
        });
});

app2.controller('formCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.login = function() {
        if ($scope.username == 'test' && $scope.password == 'test') {
            alert('valid username/password   ' + $scope.username);
            alert('user from json ' + $scope.users);

        } else {
            alert('invalid username/password   ' + $scope.username);
        }
    };
});
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
   <script src="script.js"></script>
   <body ng-app="app">
      <div  ng-controller="formCtrl">
         <form name="form">
            First Name:<br>
            <input type="text" ng-model="username"><br>
            Last Name:<br>
            <input type="text" ng-model="password">
            <br><br>
            <button ng-click="login()">LOGIN</button>
         </form>
      </div>
      <div ng-controller="jsonCtrl">
         <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="user in users">
               {{user.username}} / {{user.password}}
            </li>
         </ul>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

the problem is replace  `if ($scope.username == 'test' && $scope.password == 'test')` with anything compare with json

this my code : [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/YV93VQm4lTBtgXHgfByh?p=preview)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were using two different scopes across application. I moved all your markup under the same controller, so that is more simple manage the bindings.

Take a look [at this plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/YengGmoKYx1U0fZjznW1?p=preview)

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('formCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  $http.get('data.json')
    .then(function(res) {
      $scope.users = res.data;
    });

  $scope.login = function() {
    var u = $scope.users.filter((item) => {
      return item.username == $scope.username;
    });

    if (u[0] && u[0].password == $scope.password) {
      alert('correct');

    } else {
      alert('wr0ng');

    }
  };
});
```

```html
  <div>
    <form name="form">
      First Name:
      <br>
      <input type="text" ng-model="username">
      <br> Last Name:
      <br>
      <input type="text" ng-model="password">
      <br>
      <br>
      <button ng-click="login()">LOGIN</button>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="user in users">
        {{user.username}} / {{user.password}}
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should not authenticate user using clear text like that. Your server should do it with hashing table without knowing what is the real password.

Http.get is not synchronous which means that your application will continue its path without waiting for your data. In your plunker your formCtrl doesnt have access to jsonCtrl scope.

You should load your data in a service because it is initialised only once compared to the controller who are initialised everytime you load the page.

Finally you should start by looking at ui.router resolve, it allow you to load your data to your service before the page is displayed which will allow you to compare later.

Comment: yes i research for this idea encryption password like md5 in php

Comment: Yeah you should do it because right now anyone could see what's in your json

Comment: yes i research for this idea encryption password like md5 in php

if you can update this code with this idea

http://plnkr.co/edit/YengGmoKYx1U0fZjznW1?p=preview